# Google app engine - cannot get the referenced entity when retrieving referencer entity

Tags: java, google-app-engine, entity, google-cloud-datastore, objectify

I have two `Objectify entities`: `Object` & `Category`, and each `Object` is of a specific `Category`. So, I have added in the entity `Object` a reference (`Ref`) to the `Category` entity, but my problem is that When I retrieve the `Object` from the `datastore`, its `Category` isn't retrieved, although I have added `@Load` annotation to `Ref` declaration.

The `Category` getter & setter in `Object` entity are:

```java
@Load Ref<Category> category;

public Category getCategory() {
    return category.get();
}

public void setCategory(Category category) {
    this.category = Ref.create(category);
}
```

The query used to retrieve the object is :

```java
List<Object> objects = ofy().load().type(Object.class).list();
```

And the instruction which cannot retrieve the `Category` is:

```java
for (Object object : objects)
    object.getCategory().getName();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have cleared the `datastore` and re-saved some `data` entities and the ref seem to be working great (Maybe, there were an error when saving the `reference`)!